# Impact on performance while creating a view on a table and fetch all the data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to reduce the locking on server because some users in my application have direct rights to database and they execute query without `NOLOCK` which creates locks in database.

To reduce this, I want to create a new schema for the database and in this schema I'll create views on all tables present in the database. In this view I'll write as:

```
 select * from TABLE_NAME(nolock).
```

And then I'll give rights to users for this schema only, in this way it'll reduce locking.

Is this approach a good approach? And will it create a overhead in database?

Please suggest.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:mysql], but appears to relate only to [tag:sql-server]?

Comment: There shouldn't be any significant overhead in the database - views are just stored as the SQL statement to be executed when you select from them. **BUT**: you need to be very much aware of **what you're doing** when you're using `WITH (NOLOCK)` all over the place. You're selecting rows of data ***that might never really end up in the database*** if the transaction is rolled back. So you might get data in your query result that never ends up being stored in the database. Is that OK with your system / application?

Comment: Also: having locks in the database ***is absolutely normal*** - that shouldn't be regarded as an issue per se. The question is more: why are those locks causing issues (if at all)? That might be an indicator of poor database design and/or poor database programming practices. You should check for those issues and fix the ***root cause*** of the problem - not just apply the `WITH (NOLOCK)` band-aid everywhere without knowing what (and why) you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) on `NOLOCK` (`READUNCOMMITED`) hint:

> Specifies that dirty reads are allowed. No shared locks are issued to
>   prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current
>   transaction, and exclusive locks set by other transactions do not
>   block the current transaction from reading the locked data. Allowing
>   dirty reads can cause higher concurrency, but at the cost of reading
>   data modifications that then are rolled back by other transactions.
>   **This may generate errors for your transaction, present users with data
>   that was never committed, or cause users to see records twice (or not
>   at all)**.

If this is acceptable to you, you can consider your approach. Sure it will speed up performance of all queries. However I must say it is not very good idea, as it can cause a number of other unpredictable bugs - if you use data read with `NOLOCK` for later operations.

[Here is a nice blog pos](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx)t about dangers of using `NOLOCK` and other possible solutions you can implement to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your approach is flawed at many levels. At the very least you need to be aware of two probelms:

- NOLOCK queries [still create locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

> READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints apply only to data locks. All queries, including those with READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints, acquire Sch-S (schema stability) locks during compilation and execution. Because of this, queries are blocked when a concurrent transaction holds a Sch-M (schema modification) lock on the table.

- NOLOCK queries [produce incorrect results](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx)

You should consider two alternatives:

- Preferably create a standby read-only copy of the database just for these users to run their queries. You can use [AG readable secondaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878253.aspx) (the luxury option), standby [log shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx) databases, a local [database snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx) or, as a last option, [replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).
- As an alternative enable [read committed snapshot](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) in the database and let row versioning eliminate contention. This is arguably a worse option that having users query the standby data because row versioning consumes resources and because users, with access to the read-write data, may accidentally end up modifying the data or even modifying the schema.

Whatever you choose, just make sure you get rid of the NOLOCK. It does not help, it does not work.